# How to hide Windows 10's magnify glass (zoom)?

Tags: windows-10, magnifier

when turning on the magnify glass there is an icon of magnifier on the screen. How can we hide it while keep the magnify feature enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hover the mouse over the magnifier lens, and click on the double-arrow sign.

[image]

This shows the Magnifier window. Minimize it to the taskbar.